# How to show $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin (n b)}{n}\right)^{2}=\frac{b \pi-b^{2}}{2} $ - Parseval's identity?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I have trouble solving a). How do I approach this problem?

Let $-\pi\leq a<b\leq\pi$.  Consider the function

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1, & x \in] a, b[ \\ 0, & x \in]-\pi, \pi[\backslash[a, b]\end{array}\right.$$

It is shown that the (complex) Fourier coefficients are given by: $$c_0=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}$$
$$
c_{n}=\frac{i}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i n b}-e^{-i n a}}{n}, n\neq0
$$

**a) Use the relevant theory about fourier series and the Fourier coefficients above to show$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin (n b)}{n}\right)^{2}=\frac{b \pi-b^{2}}{2}
$$ for $b\in[0,\pi]$**

---

Immediately when I see an expression squared like that, I think of Parseval's theorem. However, I do not see what's going on with the limits when calculating the norm? Where did the $a$ disappear?

This is what I started doing, until I realized I shouldn't have any $a$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\|f\|^{2}=\left.\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\right|^{2} d x=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{a}^{b} 1 d x=\frac{b-a}{2 \pi}\\
&\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|c_{n}\right|^{2}=\left|c_{0}\right|^{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left|c_{n}\right|^{2}+\left|c_{-n}\right|^{2}\right)\\
&=\left|c_{0}\right|^{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{i}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i n b}-e^{-i n a}}{n}\right|^{2}+ \left| \frac{i}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{i n b}-e^{i n a}}{n}\right|^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=\left|c_{0}\right|^{2}+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}\left[2\left(e^{-i n b}-e^{-i n a}\right)\left(e^{i n b}-e^{i n a}\right)\right] \\
=\left|c_{0}\right|^{2}+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}\left[2\left(1-e^{i n(a-b)}-e^{-i n(a-b)}+1\right)\right] \\
=\left|c_{0}\right|^{2}+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^{2}}[2-2 i \sin (n(a-b))]
\end{array}
$$

So am I on the right track, what should I do instead?

- another question. Is it also understood correct, that if $a=-\pi$ and $b=\pi$,   $f$ would be continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus the Fourier series would converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition of using Parseval's identity is correct. If you set $a=-b$, then for $n\neq0$, $$c_{n}=\frac{i}{2 \pi} \frac{e^{-i n b}-e^{i n b}}{n}=\frac{\sin(bn)}{n\pi}.$$

Can you complete the argument from here?

---

About your second question: Indeed if $-a=b=\pi$, then $f\equiv1$ so the Fourier series converges uniformly. (A result you may use for instance is that the Fourier series converges uniformly for all functions that are periodically extendible to a $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ function.) This can also be seen "manually" as you have $c_n=\frac{\sin(\pi n)}{n\pi}=0$ whenever $n\neq0$ and $c_0\equiv f\equiv1$.